# google maps sdk error with new flutter version

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

Error: The method 'FlutterGooglePlacesSdkHttpPlugin.findAutocompletePredictions' doesn't have the named parameter 'placeTypesFilter' of overridden method 'FlutterGooglePlacesSdkPlatform.findAutocompletePredictions'.

I have upgraded the flutter version to  3.13.0 the when I run the app it return this error

flutter clean.
flutter pub get

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you tried filing an issue to the github repo itself?

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I have exactly the same error after Flutter upgrade Flutter 3.13.4.